# Set time values (specifically OriginalEstimate) using JIRA SDK

Tags: c#, jira

I've been following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/762516/Connecting-to-Jira-using-Csharp) guide on interfacing with JIRA through the Atlassian SDK.

But I've run into a brick wall when it comes to setting Issue time estimates using the SDK. I figured out a kludgey work around that lets you set the Remaining Time Estimate by adding a fake Worklog that specifies the new time:

```
jiraConn = Jira.CreateRestClient(JIRA_BASE_ADDRESS, J_USER_ID, J_PASSWORD);
Issue newIssue = jiraConn.CreateIssue("CL");
//Inadequate 'solution':
newIssue.AddWorklog("0h", WorklogStrategy.NewRemainingEstimate, "10d");
```

I'm particularly interested in being able to set the OriginalEstimate value, but any advice on setting other Time Tracking Data would be great. I also tried changing the values for the IssueTimeTrackingData object returned by issue.GetTimeTrackingData() - but that object appears to be disconnected from the JIRA DB so changes to that don't commit.

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/211138/defining-original-estimation-value-via-api ?

Comment: @o_weisman I was hoping to avoid creating REST querries and using purely the SDK functions. I'm looking for a solution that works the way editing any of the other fields works, for example: 
issue.Priority = "Low";
issue.SaveChanges();

Comment: It should now be noted that as of early 2022, the C# SDK is no longer supported, so you're probably better off getting used to the REST API if you want to work in C#. I've taken to using the SDK just to connect to Jira and from then on using Jira.RestClient.ExecuteRequestAsync for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of the JIRA SDK had SetEstimate() type methods. These were subsequently removed, so while you can access time-estimate values they can't be changed (aside from RemainingTime which can be updated by adding worklogs as described in the question).

Answer (score 1):

So I've stumbled upon this thread many times while searching for a way to set the original estimate time via the Jira's API. It's really unfortunate that Atlassian SDK in C# doesn't allow the change of the original estimated time. Worse, the exception thrown is not informative at all!

Anyway here's the solution:

```
  var jiraConnection = Jira.CreateRestClient(BASE_URL, username, password)
  var restRequest = new RestRequest("rest/api/2/issue/" + issue.JiraIdentifier);
  restRequest.Method = Method.PUT;
  restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  var requestBody = new { update = new { timetracking = new[]{ new { edit = new { originalEstimate = work.ToString()+"h" } } } } };
  restRequest.AddJsonBody(requestBody);

  IRestResponse response = jiraConnection.RestClient.ExecuteRequest(restRequest);

  if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
  {
    throw new System.Net.WebException("Error creating planning issue");
  }
```

It's based on this [solution](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-33749) using the first example. I've first tried the second solution, but it didn't work, at least for me, so you have to use the longer one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest accessing the REST API directly to update the Original Estimate

```
try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("<Jira URL>/rest/api/2/issue/" + IssueKey);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

            String username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JiraUserName"];
            String password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JiraPassword"];
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{" +
                               "\"fields\" : { " +
                               "\"timetracking\":{ \"originalEstimate\":\"12h\"  }" + 
                               "} }";
                sw.Write(json);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                httpResponse.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            WebResponse wbResponse = ex.Response;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wbResponse;
            response.Close();
        }
```